# PHP mail() from not working

Tags: php, email

I am using mail() on my site, and the function is working, but the from address is not showing my email address, it is showing name@mailchannels.net

```
$ito_email = "$inameuser";
$ifrom_email = "info@mywebsite.co.za";
$isubject = "My subject";
$icomment =  "Hello $inameuser,\r\n\r\n"
. " \r\n"
. "Subject: $isubjectnote"
. " \r\n"
. "Notice: $inote"
. " \r\n"
. "\r\n"
. "Many thanks";

//send email
mail($ito_email, "$isubject", $icomment, "From: Support " . $ifrom_email);
```

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Try `"From: Support <" . $ifrom_email . ">"`

Comment: Thanks  user2959229. Worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
mail($ito_email, "$isubject", $icomment, "From: Support " . $ifrom_email);
```

to

```
mail($ito_email, "$isubject", $icomment, "From: Support <" . $ifrom_email . ">");
```

Should allow you to include a readable name as well as the FROM e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

EXAMPLE:

```
$email = "emailfrom@anything.com";
  $headers = 'From: ' . $email . '' . "\r\n" . "Content-type: text/html;charset = windows-1250";
            $subject = $email . ' - New message';
            mail("your email", $subject, "email message", $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$to      = 'abc@xyz.com'; $subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'Message';
$headers = 'From: xyz@xyz.com' . "\r\n" .'Reply-To: xyz1@xyz.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
OR
$headers .= $headers; Concat
```